# Golang docker multi-stage build failing to run: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker, go

When deploying a simple API with a Docker multi-stage build the following error is being thrown:

```sh
$ docker build -t api:latest .
[...]
$ docker run -p 4880:4880 --rm --name=api api:latest
2019/01/29 23:02:15 exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
```

As my application is not calling `go` from anywhere (or any `exec.Command`) I ran a `go mod vendor` so I could check the dependency source code and found the following:

```
vendor/github.com/lib/pq/oid/gen.go
12:     "os/exec"
64:     cmd := exec.Command("gofmt")
```

Could this be the issue and if so how can I fix it? I am *sure* I have managed to deploy `github.com/lib/pq` in a multi-stage build before but I am currently stuck.

Many thanks and Happy Hacking.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1-alpine AS builder
ENV GO111MODULE=on
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates git
WORKDIR /app
# Copy go module info first...
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
# ...then download to cache dependencies between builds
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o api cmd/api/

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/api /app/
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["./api"]
```

Comment: Could you please make sure that `api` executable got copied from `builder`?

Comment: Can confirm by running a `RUN ls -la` in the second stage of the Dockerfile during the build and just the fact that it is running the `api`

Comment: Maybe test by skipping scratch and just run api binary in the build container and see what happens. Might give some clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual build line:

```golang
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -installsuffix cgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o api cmd/api/
```

is missing a relative path in front of `cmd`, making it instead be `./cmd/api` will result in a successful build/run. `cmd/api` is a real thing apparently, https://golang.org/cmd/api/, so it's not erring out, but also not doing what you are expecting it to do. If you type `go run cmd/api` in your terminal you should see a ton of output unrelated to your application.

Comment: Spot on - thank you! I spent too long trying to work out what was different between my local and docker builds. Thanks again